# Why isn't this working javascript?

Tags: javascript, variables

I am using this to detect errors on my form...

```
var error = false;

if (val === '') {

    error = true;
}

if (error = true) {

    $('#joinForm .submit').click(function(event) {
        event.preventDefault();
    });
}
```

Simple really but not working, am I missing something stupid? variable error is default **false**.

If an error is found it is **true**.

If error is found to be **true** it prevents the form being submitted?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
var error = false;

if (val === '') { // <<< This checks type first, then value
                  //     An empty '' variable is not type-equivalent
                  //     to a (boolean) false value
    error = true;
}

if (error = true) { // <<< You're setting a variable here, which means
                    //     means that you're testing if the variable
                    //     assignment itself is successful, you'll get
                    //     a true result in most cases, and except with
                    //     things like while loops, you shouldn't use this
                    //     form.
                    // Maybe you want == (falsy)? Or === (type-checked)?
    $('#joinForm .submit').click(function(event) {
        event.preventDefault();
    });
}
```

Comment: The code is still fundamentally broken as he's subscribing to submit clicks to prevent the event from happening, but never removes them.

Comment: @JohnD - Feel free to offer additional information in another answer. With questions like this, there are often a number of problems to focus on. `;)`

Answer (score 0):

You should do the checking in the submit event handler:

```
$('#joinForm').submit(function(event) {

    var error = false;

    if (val === '') {
        error = true;
    }

    if (error) {
        event.preventDefault();
    }
});
```